# Что такое: 2 физических / 2 логических ядра?

Tags: nginx

Здравствуйте.

Выделенный сервер с процессором Intel Atom D525.
В описании к серверу сказано: это двухъядерный процессор ... но благодаря технологии HyperThreading, способен обработать четыре потока за один раз.
Как это понять?

Вообщем моя проблема в том, что я не знаю какое значение установить для директивы worker_processes в конфигурационном файле nginx.conf

worker_processes 2; ИЛИ worker_processes 4;

Ведь по Сысоеву worker_processes должен равняться числу процессорных ядер.

Помогите подсчитать ядра :)

Comment: ядер два. Ни больше, ни меньше. Но для не очень сильных числодробилок они вполне работают как 4.

Ставьте 4, думаю будет работать. Но вообще то это вопрос на руткод, думаю там знают больше.


по факту (сильно упрощенно) - в процессоре есть АЛУ - арифметико-логическое устройство, которое умеет делать вычисления и блок работы с памятью. Так как АЛУ работает сильно быстрее, чем все остальное, то одно АЛУ может обеспечивать два ядра одновременно. Отсюда и такой способ удешевить - два ядра используют общие ресурсы.

Comment: Ну тут еще вопрос в том, сумеет ли сам nginx оптимизировать свою работу на псевдоядрах. У меня на буке intel i7, в TaskManager'e показано 8 процессоров, но все программы и тесты, которые мне приходилось запускать используют только 4 (судя по графикам нагрузки на процы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
worker_process     auto;
```

А вообще если на ваш nginx будут приходить по паре запросов в минуту то можете поставить 1 и не заморачиваться.